# TCPDF Error en Multicell

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Utilizando la librería [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) de Php, no tengo ningún problema utilizando el método cell, escribiendo línea a línea de esta forma:

```
$this->AddPage();
        
$total = 6;

for ($i=0;$i<$total;$i++) {

    if ($i == 0) {
        $this->SetXY(5,5);
    }
    else {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            $x = 5;
            $y = $this->getY()+95;
            $this->SetXY($x,$y);
        }
        else {
            $x = 105;
            $y = $this->getY();
            $this->SetXY($x,$y);
        }
    }
    
    $x = $this->getX();
    $y = $this->getY();
    $this->Cell(100,95,'',1,0,"L",0,"",0,true);
    $this->setXY($x,$y+30);
    
    $this->Cell(100, 7, 'DATOS 1',0,0,"L",0,"",0,true);
    $this->SetXY($x,$y+37);
    $this->Cell(100,7,'DATOS 2',0,0,"L",0,"",0,true);
    $this->setXY($x,$y+44);
    $this->Cell(100, 7, 'DATOS 3' , 0, 0, "L", 0, "", 0, true);
    $this->setXY($x,$y+51);
    $this->Cell(100, 7, 'DATOS 4' , 0, 0, "L", 0, "", 0, true);
    $this->setXY($x,$y);
}
```

El problema viene al cambiar el primer Cell, por MultiCell ya que quiero que pueda ocupar varías líneas si no cabe en la celda, si utilizo el Multicell que aparece en la documentación obtengo un error de ***Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 671088640 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) .... /tcpdf_min_6_2_8/tcpdf.php on line 5070***

```
$pdf->MultiCell(55, 5, 'DATOS 1', 1, 'L', 1, 0, '', '', true);
```

He revisado la configuración del php.ini y entiendo que es correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Al extender la clase TCPDF había escrito el construct. Utilizando la configuración del [ejemplo 5 de la documentación](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_005/) he resuelto el problema y puedo utilizar Multicell sin problema.